# Magento - Show product cost in backend

Tags: magento

Is there any way of showing to product cost in magento´s order view (backend)? So far I have not found an extension that does this (maybe you will :) ), so I guess I will have to do it myself.

What would be an efficient way of doing this? Maybe by overwriting the admin template? Or maybe there is a setting for this I just wasn't able to find.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I wonder what is the use of knowing this value in the order view?

Comment: I wondered that myself. However my client feels the need for this in case of discounts and that kind of stuff, just to see where he can go. Is it needed that often? I dont know. But since it is a requirement, I do not care :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, edit two templates from the `adminhtml` section. In `sales/order/view/items.phtml`, add a new `<col>` and `<th>` for your column. Then, in `sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`, add the corresponding `<td>` for that field. Use something like this to get the cost:

```
<td><?php print Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_item->getProductId())->getCost(); ?></td>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: thanks for your help buddy, but this solution does work only partly, bacause $_item->getProductId() only returns the parent product, which does not return a cost value. works with simple products though.

Comment: Do your simple products underneath the configurables have a different cost basis? It should still be possible to find the product ID you're looking for (possibly by finding the child item row and using that product ID) and display this column. Adding a little logic at the top of the page to find the /right/ product to print cost on may need some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. 
Then I have checked "cost" attribute and found that this attribute is assigned to some types of products.
So I changed it for all product types.

This works for me.
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

did it the quick way:

```
  <?php 
        if ($children = $_item->getChildrenItems())
        {
            $children = $_item->getChildrenItems();
            $ProductId = $children[0]->getProductId();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $ProductId = $_item->getProductId();
        } 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you can *create* *attribute for product*, *set attribute config in product*. Well, you can get this attribute by Magento object. Example:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
echo $product->getAttributeName();
```